# Hashing value before output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to MD5 hash a email address prior to outputting from a Rails Model. Currently my modal looks like so:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    attr_accessible :body, :name, :reply, :email
    validates_presence_of :body, :name

    def gravator
        require 'digest/md5'

        email_address = self.email.downcase

        # create the md5 hash
        hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email_address)

        # compile URL which can be used in <img src="RIGHT_HERE"...
        self.email = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"

    end
end
```

I'm wondering what the best way to convert the email field to the outputted URL from the gravator method.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you pre-calculate the hash (in a `before_save`, for example)?

Comment: Mainly so I can email the user back if needed. Although I could create a new field in the database that contains the hashed value.

Comment: I would add an extra field to save the hash or full Gravatar url and pre-calculate it just like Sergio said. That way you won't need to hash it every time it's displayed and still have access to the original e-mail address.

Comment: Yup that is what I have gone for now, I can see it being faster than hashing every comment, every time it is retrieved. Thanks for the help Sergio and Bitterzoet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than hashing it every time, create a new field in the database that contains the hashed value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `gravator` field and assign it on `before_save`. This will speed things up and won't call the database each time it is displayed.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    attr_accessible :body, :name, :reply, :email
    validates_presence_of :body, :name
    before_save :set_gravator

    def set_gravator
        require 'digest/md5'

        email_address = self.email.downcase

        # create the md5 hash
        hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email_address)

        # compile URL which can be used in <img src="RIGHT_HERE"...
        self.gravator = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
    end
end
```